# Meaning of the word "out"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning  of the word ***"out"*** in the sentence below?

> This here is Charlie Ledbetter... sitting in his cell **out** at the state penitentiary.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. We need to know what research you have done before we can help you, though. What kind of word is _out?_ Is it a preposition. or a verb, or ... what? What do _you_ think it means here? Use the [edit] link to add details to your question. Please read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you understand how to use our site.

Comment: Compare the word **yonder**.

Comment: @P.E.Dant and TRomano I found the mean it's **phrasal verb** sit something out: to stay in a place and wait for something unpleasant or boring to finish.

I am going to delete this  question, thanks!!!

reference:
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sit-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *out* has so many uses in English that it can easily be a source of some confusion for a new student of the language.

In commentary, you mentioned that you had come across the *phrasal* verb "sit out", defined [**here**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sit-out) as: "to stay in a place and wait for something unpleasant or boring to finish".

It is tempting to apply that usage here, since nothing is more unpleasant or boring than sitting in a cell "out at the state penitentiary"; but this is not an instance of the phrasal verb. With a little reconfiguration, we *could* use the phrasal in your sentence:

> This here is Charlie Ledbetter... **sitting** his sentence **out**, in a cell at the state penitentiary.

<sup>(Digression: Notice that I have separated the parts of the phrasal verb (which are in a bold font.) The parts of this phrasal can be separated, but this is not true of all phrasal verbs.)</sup>

In your example, though, the verb in the dependent clause is just *sitting,* not *sitting out,* and the word *out* is an adverb which describes where the *sitting* takes place.

The OED defines this adverbial usage as:

> **15.** At a distance from an accustomed place.
>     **a.** Away from one's home or usual location at a distant place; far away, abroad.